# A way to simplify this if/else block

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an `<input type="number />` that may or may not have `min` or `max` values set. If the user enters a number outside that range, I want to print an error message. I have the error handling figured out but I'm trying to find a "nicer" way to determine which error message to print.

```js
if(!!min && !!max && (val < min || val > max)) {
    print(`Enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`);
} else if(!!min && val < min) {
    print(`Enter a number greater than ${min}`);
} else if(!!max && val > max) {
    print(`Enter a number less than ${max}`);
}
```

Is there a better way to structure this if/else block?

Comment: Why not simply print `Enter a number between ${min} and ${max}` in all cases?

Comment: A couple of things: If min or max are 0, the relevant condition will be false. Template literals must be surrounded with backticks `\``, wrapping `"${max}"` will just display as-is, not show the value of `max`

Comment: @jarmod, sorry if it was unclear, there are cases where `min` will be set but `max` will not, and vice versa. Hence the need for error strings only containing one of those variables

Comment: It's a small difference but im not sure in this case what `!!min` gives you over `min`. It's a loose cast to a boolean, and `0` will become false. This means your checks will fail if min or max is set to `0` which I'm not sure is what yo uwant. Aside from that problem this looks pretty reasonable to me. What's your issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
if ((!!min && val < min) || (!!max && val > max)) {
  let errorMessage = '';

  if (!!min && !!max) {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`;
  } else if (!!min) {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number greater than ${min}`;
  } else if (!!max) {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number less than ${max}`;
  }

  print(errorMessage);
}
```

---

### OR

---

```
if(!!max && val > max) {
  print(`Enter a number less than ${max}`);
} else {
  print(`Your number is ${val}`);
}

// Answer:
if (min && max) {
  if (val < min || val > max) {
    print(`Enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`);
  } else {
    print(`Your number is ${val}`);
  }
} else if (min && val < min) {
  print(`Enter a number greater than ${min}`);
} else if (max && val > max) {
  print(`Enter a number less than ${max}`);
} else {
  print(`Your number is ${val}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation when min/max are undefined when unset. This also avoids the 0 border case…

```
if (val < min || val > max) {
  let errorMessage;
  if (max === undefined) {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number greater than ${min}`;
  } else if (min === undefined) {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number less than ${max}`;
  } else {
    errorMessage = `Enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`;
  }
  print(errorMessage);
}
```